# Remember users choice on website

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a page named index.php where I have a list of cities I'm providing weather informations for. When user chose a city the URL looks like index.php?mesto=city (where the "city" is the actual name of the city).

What I want is for users to be able to click on some link on the page (when they chose a city) and save their city choice so the next time they visit the page that exact city will be opened automatically.

Do note that this is not registered users or something, so I'm not sure in which directions should I go. Cookies? And what would be the best approach?

Comment: Take a look at [JS localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You could save the data on the web browser of the client.

Comment: I would use `LocalStorage`, with cookies as fallback mechanism for ancient browsers.